# in c# use math package for multidimensional (multivariate) interpolation

Tags: c#, python, scipy, interpolation, python.net

I plan to use a mathematical library, which can calculate multidimensional interpolation most likely in irregular grid and non-linear (like spline). Performance is important. Some points used for interpolation are going to change over time. I like interpolation function in Mathematica and in scipy/numpy, but need something stand-alone, e.g. a DLL. The wrapping code is going to be in C#.

I'm hesitant about packages in this Q&A:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net

Comment: Try with [Math.Net Numerics](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/), it will probably meet most of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I ended up using combination of `scipy` and `pythonnet`